# Reset data-toggle buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Can someone point me out why can't I reset the buttons to original state after making it active when the reset button is clicked?

```
function resetbtnstate() {
    $(.btn-group).removeClass('active');
}
```

JSFiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to wrap your selector in quotes: `$(.btn-group)` ought to be `$('.btn-group')`. Additionally, the class `active` is being applied to the buttons, not to the `btn-group` elements, so it needs to be as follows:

```
function resetbtnstate() {
    $('button').removeClass('active');
}
```

You could also use any other valid selector which would target the buttons, such as `$('.btn').removeClass('active');`, or even something clever such as `$('.active').removeClass('active');`.

Comment: Thank you.  If I wanted to target all the active buttons under the btn-group, how do I do that then?

Comment: `$('.btn-group>.active')`. > is the child selector.